# Facebook Php Sdk Permissions Error

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, permissions

Hello I have this insisting problem which is driving me nuts .

Well I have an app on facebook and when user clicks on cancel at the permissions dialog the app redirects him on the same page which is a loop and asks him again for permissions ..

I tried to change the flow of the app playing with the $_GET['error'] or $_GET['error_description'] but no luck at all as the app is inside an iframe so I cannot have access to parent window's url .

I have checked and tried everything but no light at all please help. All I want is to implement somehow the cancel action.

Comment: Easiest fix: Don’t redirect to the login dialog automatically, but only trigger login on explicit user interaction (e.g. click on a link/button). Also generally recommended, because you should give the user a chance to see what your app is about, before asking them to log in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what I ask for , I want to handle the cancel button and the data is lost ..

Comment: Are we talking about a page tab app here? Since your app runs inside an iframe, you will only get the data that Facebook passes through to it … and AFAIK _this_ info is not passed. So I think your only chance of actually getting the info is to set your redirect_uri to point outside of facebook.com, to your app’s website URL – and from there redirect back to your page tab, passing the necessary info via the `app_data` parameter …

Comment: And btw., from within an app on Facebook, it makes for a much nicer user experience if you use the JS SDK to handle login, no ugly popup … and you would get the error response much more easily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I will definitely have a look at fb js sdk , I fixed the issue by adding an app_data variable I will provide below an example.